# How to return 204 with Nginx Ingress K8S

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

Is it possible to configure Nginx Ingress to return 204 on a given path?

In Nginx, it would look like this:

location / {
return 204;
}

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location /ping {
        return 204;
        }
```

More information here:
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-snippet

And here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782415/nginx-ingress-config-map-snippets-being-ignored-by-the-nginx-conf

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this in AWS scenarios mentioned here: https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/ingress/annotations/#actions

nginx supports some annotations like `nginx.org/location-snippets` (https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/#snippets-and-custom-templates), which might allow you to pass in an nginx location in the way you describe above.

But I don't know if there is a generic way.

Comment: Thank you! You put me on the right way, in fact I had to add annotation on "server-snippet".